How to import and merge multiple meshes with different textures into one mesh
Is there any way to merge multiple meshes with different textures into one mesh(USDz)?
Right now I cannot even import two meshes with different textures into Blender....
Here are two files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QBCLCyrQ_9jvIKBFIZKEEITx5ebNjS18?usp=share_link
Thank you

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

The problem with your two files is, there are no unique names for materials and textures. This way after importing one of them, the second one automatically uses the same image texture as the first one, because since these files are complete scene descriptions, to Blender it looks like there is one image texture in the scene and both objects use it. I do not know where you got them from, when I use different files they usually have different names for materials and image textures so this issue does not occur.
But in your case, to avoid the double use of textures, there are two possible ways to go:

You import one USDz file into a new scene, and save this as a Blender file. Then you create another new scene, import the second USDz file. Then you go to File > Append and explore the previously saved file to append the collection that's in there. This way, Blender will rename the material and image texture to separate them from the other.

This is the easiest way I think. Another would be:

Create a new scene and save it before importing anything. Then when importing the first USDz file, go to the import options on the right and scroll all the way down to Import Textures and change it from Packed to Copy. By default it then uses the relative path "//textures/" (which only works if you saved the file beforehand to determine the path this folder is relative to).

After import, you have to go to the "textures" folder and rename the image file. Then back in Blender, in the Shader Editor you have to change the Image Texture in the material of the object to the one with the new name with Open. But now the datablock with the old image and filename still remains in the scene, so to get rid of it go to File > Clean Up > Recursive Unused Data-Blocks. Now you can import the second USDz file into the scene and it will get his own texture.




Thank you for this very detailed answer! I chose the second one, it works very well for me.

Thank you!! And thank you, @Oscar for asking the question. Huge help! The first option worked beautifully for me when importing two USDZ files I made via photogrammetry.
